# Change label text on Input Box value change

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using Blazor framework with ASP.NET Core 3.0.

I have a Input Box and I added a Label HTML next to it. When user enters, say 5, in the Input Box, the Label should show calculated value of 5/2. That is, value of Input Box divide by 2.

In the Blazor framework, I am not understanding how to add jQuery.

Code is something like this:

```
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-secondary" @bind="myModel.CarWeight[index]" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                @if (myModel.AppType == "LC" || myModel.AppType == "LN")
                {
                    decimal calcRes = Convert.ToDecimal(myModel.CarWeight[index]) / 2;
                    
                     <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="justify-content-center mb-2">
                            <label class="col-form-label"><b>calcRes</b></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
```

Please note this line: myModel.CarWeight[index]

When the page is loaded, it creates an entry Form of 5 rows and 2 columns. 5 input boxes. When user fills any of the input box, I want the corresponding label to show the calculation.

Comment: Please, post all your code.

Comment: @enet This is the complete code of calculation I wrote. Pasting entire page code not possible due to official information in it.

Comment: Je might want to add what blazor you use like serverside or webassembly. Also wy use jquery when you have blazor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update bind value on specific event

> @bind:event="oninput"

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

You get this very simple code

```
@page "/"

<input type="number" @bind="inputVal" @bind:event="oninput" />
<label>@(Convert.ToDouble(inputVal)/2)</label>

@code{
    string inputVal = "0";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Worked with few tweaks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe somebody will come up with better idea to achieve what you want, but currently you could try something like this with C# code (.NET 5.0.103):

---

```
@page "/SampleComponent"

<input type="number" @bind="Operations[0].Input" @oninput="@( (input) => Calculate(input, 0))"/> 
<label>@Operations[0].Result</label>
<input type="number" @bind="Operations[1].Input" @oninput="@( (input) => Calculate(input, 1))"/> 
<label>@Operations[1].Result</label>

@code {

    public List<Operation> Operations = new List<Operation>();
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        Operations.Add(new Operation{Input = 0, Result = 0});
        Operations.Add(new Operation{Input = 0, Result = 0});
    }
    
    public void Calculate(ChangeEventArgs input, int id)
    {
        float result;

        if(float.TryParse((string)input.Value, out result))
        {
            Operations[id].Result = result/2;
        }
        else
        {
            Operations[id].Result = 0;
        }
    }

    public class Operation
    {
        public float Input { get; set; }
        public float Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```